# Importing cordova exported project into android studio

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, phonegap-desktop-app

I want to know if I´ve imported the project correctly, because to have two grade and packets is not usual for me.
After import the project into Android Studio my tree is as follows:

```
CordovaLib
  |-manifests
    |-AndroidManifest.xml
  |-java
    |-org.apache.cordova
Myapp
  |-manifests
    |-AndroidManifest.xml
  |-java
    |-com.myapp.idh
  |-res
    |-drawable
    |-layout
    |-values
    |-xml
  |-jniLibs  --> It´s empty 
  |-assets
    |-www -->css, img, js, res, cordova.js, cordova_plugin.js and index.html
 Gradle Scripts
  |-build.gradle (Module:CordovaLib)
  |-cordova.gradle (Module:CordovaLib)
  |-build.gradle (Module:Myapp)
  |-settings.grade
```

Are those paths right? Because when I programmed in Android Studio to do a native Android app, the paths are completely different and I want to know if those are correct because my app is not working fine in Android. I testes the app in iOS and works perfect but to migrate to Android is really difficult now for me gettings some php errors that can be done by the libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure that Android Studio is best for Cordova apps, it's designed for native (java) apps: (from Cordova API documents) "Procceed with Android Studio if you plan developing new Cordova for Android plugins or using native tools to run and debug Android platform"

Comment: I have exported  the project to test it in android before upload it to the market. The app works fine in ios, but not in android. So I had to export the project and import in android studio to debug it. I'm in the last stage before finish the app for Android.